# Insurance against flight with a bad record of delays?

Tags: air-travel, insurance, delays

I am flying into CDG Paris and have a TGV train to another French city. I paid well in advance for both flight and train sometime ago to get the best possible prices. I thought I had time to clear baggage claims and immigration at the CDG (~2 hrs). But now I realize the flight I am taking has a very bad on time record and is often delayed in excess of 4 hrs. In such a case I will definitely miss the train, will have to buy an expensive ticket on the next day and stay in a hotel overnight as it is the last train on the day.

Does it make sense to get some travel insurance against this scenario ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes it makes absolute sense to do so, if your carrier is know to be a troublesome one. It is always worthwhile to have travel insurance, you know not what may happen.

These are the clippings for the required sections I have on my travel insurance(UK one). You probably can assume it to be same across all providers, but you should check anyway for the amounts they can cover, depends on the policy and the cover you take. There would be some excluding conditions too on the policy, always read between the lines for such.

> - Delayed departure
>
> We will pay for each full 12 hour period you are delayed (up to the amount shown in the table of benefits), as long as you eventually go on the trip.
>
> - What you are covered for
>
> If the first part of your booked outward or final return international journeys (by aircraft, ship, cruise ship, coach or cross-channel train) is delayed because of a strike  or industrial action, poor weather conditions or a mechanical breakdown we will pay for delayed departure up to the amounts shown on the table of benefits. You must be delayed by  at least 12 hours on each occasion.
>
> - Missed departure
>
> We will pay up to the amount shown in the table of benefits for the extra reasonable costs of travel and accommodation you need to continue your trip if you cannot reach the original departure point of your trip on the outward or final return journey, as a result of public transport services failing (due to poor weather conditions, a strike, industrial action or a mechanical breakdown) or the vehicle you are travelling in being stuck in traffic, involved in an accident or having a mechanical breakdown. (This would not include your vehicle running out of petrol, oil or water, having a flat tyre or flat battery).

Comment: Does `We will pay for each full 12 hour period you are delayed (up to the amount shown in the table of benefits), as long as you eventually go on the trip.` mean that only delays `>= 12h` will be paid for?

Comment: @JoErNanO - Yes it seems so. I had taken the cheapest one(cost me £27 for a year) available so the harsh conditions. The more you pay more friendlier the insurance conditions are.

Comment: This makes me wonder what the insurer considers "extra reasonable costs of travel and accommodation you need to continue your trip".  I bet it's not an equivalent TGV ticket.  It may turn out to be whatever the cheapest and slowest form of public transportation there is.